# Use cases of csrf_exempt

Tags: python, django, csrf-protection, django-csrf

May I know where could we use Django [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt). In my current application, I have seen many places where programmers have used csrf_exempt. I suspect there could be a security flaw. So it would be helpful if I'm able to understand different use cases.

Answer (score 2):

csrf_exempt can be used where you do not have a way to set the csrftoken cookie in the request. If you are accepting requests from cross domains it will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your controller does. You should have some middleware or signal kind of approach to validate your request. If your controller is writting something raw data to DB, you should avoid `csrf_exempt` until unless your url is open for some webhook. For REST apis you can use [CORS HEADER](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) instead of making `csrf_exempt` (though it has some limitation when Your REST is public)